# Can $\min f'x$ s.t. $(a'x - b)^2 \le d $ be written as a SOCP?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

It does not appear to be significantly different from the form listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming) with (in article notation) $i = {1}$, $ A = a$, and $b$, $d$ as scalars. Or is $m$ something special?

If it is possible, what is the equivalent SOC constraint? If not, can this be solved with a specialised solver, or should I defer to more general non linear optimizers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite the constraint as

$y= a^Tx-b$

$||y||_2 \leq \sqrt d$

and you are back to SOC. Or you can set $(0.5,d,a^Tx -b)\in Q_r$, where $Q_r$ is the rotated cone.

Comment: I'm new to this, so please forgive me if this is a silly question, but does this add the constraint that $a'x -b \ge 0$. Also, please can you explain the notation in the second part of your answer or point to a reference.

Comment: no it doesn't. for more details you might want to look at http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/

Comment: Thank you for the reference.